# Prove "Contractible implies simply connected" using tools in Munkres Topology. Context is theta-space.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I've read this online, but I haven't seen this proved in Munkres Topology. Has it been? If so, where?

In any case, here is my attempt to show it **using the tools given in the book**. Please verify.

The book has 2 exercises on contractible spaces. One says contractible spaces are path connected and the other says a space is contractible if and only if the space has the same homotopy type of a one-point space. Since simply connected is defined as path connected and trivial fundamental group, I think that if a space has the same homotopy type as that of a one-point space, then the fundamental group of the space is trivial. Is that right? If so, I can work out the details myself.

Exercise 51.3b

[image]

Exercise 58.5

[image]

Definition of fundamental group

[image]

Definition of simply connected

[image]

---

The context is the claim made here in Example 70.1

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought of one. Use Corollary 58.6 with $h$ as the identity map.

[image]

Since $h$ is nullhomotopic by definition of contractible, the induced homomorphism $h_{*}$ is both the identity isomorphism and the trivial homomorphism.

This means all loop classes are what they are mapped to, which is the identity class!

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the definitions:

If $X$ is contractible this means there is a point $x_0 \in X$ and a continuous $H: X \times I \to X$ such that $H(x,0) = x$ for all $x \in X$, $H(x,1) = x_0$ for all $x \in X$. (i.e. The identity is homotopic to a constant map)

This means that if $x \in X$, the map $p_x: [0,1] \to X$ defined by $p_x(t) = H(X,t)$ is continuous (it's the composition of $H$ with the map $t \to (x,t)$ which are both continuous) and it's a path from $p_x(0) = H(x,0)= x$ to $p_x(1) = H(x,1) = x_0$.

As we have a path from any $x$ to this fixed $x_0$, $X$ is path-connected: to get a path from $x$ to $y$, compose the path $p_x$ with the reverse path of $p_y$: 
$p(t) = H(x,2t)$ for $t \le \frac12$, $p(t) = H(y, 2-2t)$ for $t \ge \frac12$, which is continuous by the pasting lemma for $[0,\frac12]$ and $[\frac12,1]$, as the two definitions coincide for $t=\frac12$, as $H(x,1) = H(y,1) = x_0$.

This defines a path from $x$ to $y$ directly from the homotopy $H$.

Now point (c) of exercise 3 implies that $[I,X]$ has but one element (the class of the constant map, which always is in any $[I,X]$) and this set already almost equal to $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ (the difference being that the homotopy must keep end-points fixed all the time). So we almost have that $X$ is simply connected: path-connected (see above) and $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ a single element for some $x_0$ (almost, keeping endpoints fixed is the only possible issue)...

Comment: OK. I saw I needed to show simple-connectedness. More thought needed.

Comment: It comes for free as long as your contraction is a deformation retraction onto $x_0$ (these are the assumptions in your first paragraph). In favorable situations, we can modify a contraction to a deformation retraction onto a point, but this is not always guaranteed. (It is easy to prove, for instance, if you replace $X$ with $X \cup_{x_0} I$ - that is, $X$ with a whisker attached along $x_0$. Now you need to show these have the same pointed homotopy type, which requires some demands on the space.)

Comment: On the other hand, here is an argument that implies that you do not need the contraction to preserve the basepoint. 1) Free homotopy classes of loops in $X$ are identified with conjugacy classes in $\pi_1(X, x_0)$. 2) A contractible space has one free homotopy class of loop. 3) A group with only one conjugacy class is trivial, because the identity element is not conjugate to anything else.

Comment: @MikeMiller For a deformation retraction I would need $H(x_0,t)=x_0$ for all $t$, which was not in my first paragraph. If we would have it we'd be done straight away. But IIRC there are spaces $X$ such that $1_X$ is homotopic to the constant map $x_0$ without $x_0$ being a deformation retract of $X$.

Comment: I made a mistake in reading your definition. My apologies. There absolutely are spaces that admit a contraction without admitting a deformation retraction to a point (easier to cook up examples so that you can't d.r. to a specific point, but there are some that you cannot d.r. to any point).

Comment: Henno Brandsma, is my proof sketch (the one that doesn't use the definition directly) correct?

Comment: @JackBauer I think so, but I wanted to avoid notions like homotopy equivalent to a point etc. It would work , see also Mike Miller's comments in this thread.

Comment: Thank you , and thank you @MikeMiller !

Comment: Henno Brandsma and @MikeMiller, is my answer correct?